# Django REST Framework: deserializing a list of objects

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I want to accept a JSON data like below:

```
{
    'id': 166,
    'data_lines': [
        {
            'name': 'string',
            'quantity': '1',
            'id': '1'
        },

        {
            'name': 'string',
            'quantity': '2',
            'id': '12'
        },

        {
            'name': 'string',
            'quantity': '3',
            'id': '18'
        }
    ],
}
```

and I want to be able to build a simple shopping basket out of it by deserializing the data

The issue is, I have at this point three serializers that are involved.

In one of them, let's call it MiddleSerializer, I have:

```
class MiddleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    thing = ThingSerializer()
```

I just want to pass that ThingsSerializer an incoming id and let it handle its own stuff. It all works fine and dandy, when I pass a dict with the key 'thing' in it.

Howevever, I want to be able to have a list of these and I have a serializer that this MiddleSerializer one is nested inside. It looks like below:

```
class TopSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_other_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    things = serializers.ListField(child=MiddleSerializer())
    # I also tried the above with (many=True)
```

But when I pass this TopSerializer my data, it gives me an error about missing keyword 'thing' which is required.

How should I set the serializers up so that i can pass the list of data? I have a feeling I could utilize PrimaryKeyRelatedField() somehow, since ThingSerializer() is ModelSerializer. But I found the docs a bit unclear on how to use this from a non-model serializer and I'm not sure if it will serve the purpose. Likely so.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be more of a mistake in my thought process. Formatting the JSON like below did the trick.

```
{
    'thing': {
        'name': 'string',
        'id': '18',
    },
    'quantity': '3'
}
```